# Login controls redirecting to default.aspx when login is successful

Tags: asp.net

I use the following login controls.  Problem is if user logs in correctly it automatically redirects to default.aspx.  I just want it to stay on the login page.  Any ideas?

code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h1>Log in to Management</h1>



    <p>
&nbsp;<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
    CreateUserText="Sign Up for a New Account" CreateUserUrl="SignUp.aspx">
                </asp:Login>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                You are already logged in!
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
    </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web.config file change the defaulturl property to login.aspx if you want it to redirect to that page. I assume login.aspx is your login page.

```
<authentication mode="forms">
<forms loginurl="index.aspx" defaulturl="login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

MSDN links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx